# Set Kendo Grid Filter Cell Value

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to **set a filter cell's value in Kendo Grid** in code? We're using 'row' mode with operators turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a filter value of your own you'll have to set it on the grid's dataSource.

You can do it when you initialize the data source using the [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) parameter:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    filter: { field: "YourFiledName", operator: "startWith", value: "A" }
    //Other parameters...
  }
});
```

... or you can do it after the grid initialization if you need to by using the dataSource [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter) method:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "YourFiledName", operator: "startWith", value: "A" });
```

Comment: This does set the filter, but it does NOT set the filter's cell value (see image above).  The grid does implement the filter, but there still no value in the filter cell (UI). Any ideas?

Comment: I does for me... in both case.  Do you have the latest version of kendo?

Comment: Do you have showOperators = false? I do have the latest Kendo UI.

Comment: I do have your code working in a fiddle. So, it must be something in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the filter-field of the datasource?
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter

Snippet from that page:

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
  ],
  filter: { field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" }
});
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var view = dataSource.view();
  console.log(view.length); // displays "1"
  console.log(view[0].name); // displays "Jane Doe"
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will set the filter, but not the filter cell's value.

Answer (score 0):

You should just provide initial filter to the dataSource. Check the API reference [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter).